# Objective C - [CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] prior to iOS 4.2

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I was just reading that this delegate has only been added in iOS 4.2

```
[CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:]
```

Turn out having that method crashed devices with older iOS version.
What would be the equivalent of that method in iOS 4.1 for example?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier versions, you the `locationManager:didFailWithError:` delegate method will be called with error saying `kCLErrorDenied`

Comment: Thanks Denis, that's weird coz I actually also have method locationManager:didFailWithError. Why would I get this error when the user is on 4.1? <Error>: +[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e2ee618
Thu Nov 17 12:23:49 unknown  <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e2ee618'. Looks like  locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: is getting called instead of locationManager:didFailWithError:

Comment: earlier, the only way to be informed about error - was handling didFailWithError delegate method, so when user denied location access, on next attempt to get location - you will receive didFailWithError; in 4.2 Apple added more comfortable separate notification about user disallowing access to location data for the application; the reason for the crash is indeed in the authorizationStatus selector sending, it just doesn't exist in the iOS prior 4.2; so you must check for the actual iOS version, before calling it

Answer (score 1):

Having the locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: delegate method in your code did not cause your crash.  Somewhere you must have sent an authorizationStatus message to the CLLocationManager instance which isn't recognized prior to 4.2.

Comment: Thanks, yeah found it to be somewhere else. Sometimes you just don't look at the bigger picture after staring at the code for so long. D'oh.